# How does an object with gravitational energy exhaust that energy as work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

To my understanding (which is pretty basic) energy is the ability to do work. The higher objects are above a point - more gravitational energy they have relatively to that point, which means that they can do more work than lower objects relatively to that point.

But I do not understand it. If I am in an airplane, can I kick a ball harder than someone on the ground? How that gravitational energy becomes work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential energy is the ability to perform work in the way that...

- potential energy $U$ is converted into kinetic $K$ energy during the fall.
- The kinetic energy implies a speed $v$ and thus causes a momentum $p=mv$.
- On impact this momentum is reduced drastically causing a force $F=dp/dt$.
- Is the impact-surface displaced by x, then the work $W=Fx$ has been done.

For example:

> Drop a stone on a mill wheel. The mill wheel blade is hit and set in motion (displaced) by the force resulting from the momentum change of the stone. That the mill wheel blade is moved means that the mill wheel has been rotated - plug a generator to this mill wheel and drop many stones (or put it under a water or air stream) to keep up rotation, and the generator will convert this rotational kinetic energy into electrical energy.

In this example, work is done every time a force causes displacement. Work is only *energy in transit* so to speak, or a method of *energy conversion* from one form to another, so it doesn't appear clearly in the example. But it *is* a part of the process, since work is causing several of the energy conversion steps, for example the one from kinetic energy of the falling stone to rotational kinetic energy of the mill wheel.